# How do I place the corresponding tags in this xml to a java object

Tags: java, xml

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dragonDatabase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <dragon>
        <Name>Hackatoo</Name>
        <Description>This impulsive and reckless member of the Sharp Class is a master at collecting wood...so long as its axe-like snout doesn't get stuck in the tree its cutting! Hackatoo eggs laid at a high altitude can hook on to whatever they hit.</Description>
        <Class>Sharp</Class>
        <Fire-Type>No Data</Fire-Type>
        <Diet>No Data</Diet>
    </dragon>
    <dragon>
        <Name>Hobblegrunt</Name>
        <Description>The Hobblegrunt has a single horn and and an expandable frill surrounding its head. It has clawed wings, small arms and big legs like a Deadly Nadder. It also appears to have long neck and tail as well. The Hobblegrunt doesn't have a particular color, but instead it changes color depending on its mood.</Description>
        <Class>Stoker, Boulder</Class>
        <Fire-Type>Ethane Expectorant</Fire-Type>
        <Diet>No Data</Diet>
    </dragon>
</dragonDatabase>
```

And this is my DragonBean class:

```
public class DragonBean {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String dragonClass;
    private String fireType;
    private String diet;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getDragonClass() {
        return dragonClass;
    }
    public void setDragonClass(String dragonClass) {
        this.dragonClass = dragonClass;
    }
    public String getFireType() {
        return fireType;
    }
    public void setFireType(String fireType) {
        this.fireType = fireType;
    }
    public String getDiet() {
        return diet;
    }
    public void setDiet(String diet) {
        this.diet = diet;
    }

}
```

Basically I want to get each dragon in the xml and place it in a list containing the a DragonBean type. I know that I have to parse the XML. But i don't know where to begin. After placing the info in the list I plan to use Jackson to convert it into a JSON file.

Comment: JaxB is the answer..........?

Comment: I know how to use JAXB but only if there is one Dragon tag and not multiple dragon tags

Comment: Accept it as a list of dragon?

Comment: @Nate Your file contains one element, of type DragonDatabase, that contains a list of elements, of type Dragon. So, just unmarshall the XML to a DragonDatabase object.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please show an example? If I make a dragonDatabaseObject how do I get list of elements which are supposed to be of type DragonBean?

Comment: By calling `dragonDatabase.getDragons()` on the DragonDatabase bean, which has a property of type `List<DragonBean>`, in order to match the structure of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Using DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder classes, parse the xml file . First get node list of dragon and then iterate over it one by one. Get child nodes in each iteration and then read get text content of those tags and set your model class . will work . Hope it helps!